# How can I train from BigQuery instead of csv files in Cloud ML?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-ml

My training data is in BigQuery. How can I use it to train a model in Cloud ML?

Answer (score 5):

Change the preprocessing pipeline to use `BigQuerySource` (use the same `Features` class as in the CSV samples).  Here’s an example:

```
feature_set = CsvFeatures()
train_query = “SELECT …”
valid_query = “SELECt …”
train = pipeline | 'read_train' >> beam.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=train_query))
eval = pipeline | 'read_valid' >> beam.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=valid_query))
(metadata, train_features, eval_features) = ((train, eval) |
    ml.Preprocess('Preprocess', feature_set))
```